# Mapping URL in Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I have the following navigation links

```
<li><a href="account">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="ewallet/register">Register E-Wallet</a></li>
```

Both links refer to a page template which contains an `img` element as follows

```
<img src="resources/images/tdyslogo.png" alt="logo" width="150px" border="0">
```

The issues:

1. upon clicking the second link, the img element is resolving to wrong URL that is  `/business/ewallet/resources/images/tdyslogo.png` thus image not loaded
2. when I tried to access other navigation links, the URL also resolving to wrong url `/business/ewallet/account` hence I get `404` upon clicking

I tried to change my mvc:resources to `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />` in order to map any URL containing `resources` to the correct resources folder but no avail.

Based on [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls) it seems like I need to use relative or absolute URL correctly. If this is correct, how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would conventionally have all the images in a static resources that is under the root, so

```
<img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/tdyslogo.png'/>" alt="logo" width="150px" border="0">
```

Should work, using jsp c tag, which is included like below :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: The image still fail to load. The only way to make it visible after pressing the second link is by changing the src to `<img src="../resources/images/tdyslogo.png" alt="logo" width="150px" border="0">`

Comment: have altered answer to use the c url jsp tag

Comment: the generated img element is wrong (`<img src="&lt;c:url value='/resources/images/tdyslogo.png'/&gt;" alt="logo" width="150px" border="0">`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. By the way the second issue still goes unanswered. Maybe I should create a separate question

Comment: the c:url is relative, oh the /business/ewallet/account is not what you want ? I use c:url for everything, links images etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tomcat server then try with [default servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/default-servlet.html) to serve static resoruces directly.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Better use `c:url` and use prefix `/` in the value to make the url relative the context path.

```
<img id="logo" src="<c:url value='/resources/images/logo.png'/>" />
```

Dynamic project structure:

```
WebContent
         |
         |__resources
         |          |
         |          |__images
         |                   |
         |                   |__logo.png
         |
         |__WEB-INF
                  |
                  |__web.xml
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097408/how-to-call-images-from-file-system/25097689#25097689)

Comment: Added that but doesn't solve the issue. This issue only appearing when clicking on link which has `/`. E.g `<a href="ewallet/register">`. Other links are fine.

Comment: Follow the link I have shared the JSP code as well.